# Numbering elements in vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a vector of integers. For example:  **26 58 32 47** . I need to replace them with their number in that sequence. In this case it would be:  **4 1 3 2** . I tried this code:

```
int n = 1;
    vector <int> vietos;
    for (vector <int>::iterator i = vieta.begin(); i != vieta.end(); i++) {
        for (vector <int>::iterator j = vieta.begin(); j != vieta.end(); j++) {
            if (*i > *j)
                n++;
        }
            vietos.push_back(n);
            cout << n << "  ";
            n = 1;
    }
```

Having numbers  **23 25 38 28 26 28**  (Note: In this case I number them in reverse order!) I get:  **1 2 6 4 3 4**  which is good except for two numbers are equal.

Maybe there is some way to number elements in vector using STL algorithms?

Comment: What's the expected output of `23 25 38 28 26 28`?

Comment: If I would have 23 25 38 28 26 28 28 I would need it to be 1 2 7 4 3 5 6

Comment: I'm not sure about STL but you can reduce your time complexity if you follow the quickselect (a variation of quicksort) algorithm.

Comment: It is totally unclear how you got  4 1 3 2 for numbers  26 58 32 47

Comment: In that case, I numbered them in normal order, just an example...

Comment: @Modestas_S I have not understood what is the "normal order". I think that the "normal order" is simply 1, 2, 3, 4:)

Comment: In my code, I number them in reverse order. For normal order you just need to swich *i > *j with *i < j*.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The numbers are positions of elements in the list sorted in reverse order.

Comment: 26 is smallest so it is 4th, 58 is biggest so it is 1st, 32 is third and 47 is second. The order basically remains.

Comment: @Modestas_S It seems that I have at last understood.:)

Comment: @Modestas_S Though you already marked one solution but I have a better solution. :) You was hurry.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow What solution do you have? :)

Comment: @Modestas_S Well, I will show it now hoping that you will up-vote it.:) It is indeed interesting approach.

Comment: Well, I would, but I can't vote anything up yet.

Comment: @Modestas_S All is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the simplest way is to use `std::reference_wrapper`. The code will look simple and very clear.

Here is the program that demonstrates the approach.

Enjoy!:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 23, 25, 38, 28, 26, 28 };

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Introducing a local block scope that the auxiliary vector would be automatically deleted
    {
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vr( v.begin(), v.end() );

        std::stable_sort( vr.begin(), vr.end() );

        for ( std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>::size_type i = 0;
                  i < vr.size();
                  i++ )
        {
            vr[i].get() = i + 1;
        }

    }

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
23 25 38 28 26 28 
1 2 6 4 3 5
```

If you need to get the reverese order all you need is to add to the code functional object

```
std::greater<std::reference_wrapper<int>>()
```

in the call of `std::stable_sort`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 23, 25, 38, 28, 26, 28 };

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Introducing a local block scope that the auxiliary vector would be automatically deleted
    {
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vr( v.begin(), v.end() );

        std::stable_sort( vr.begin(), vr.end(),
                              std::greater<std::reference_wrapper<int>>() );

        for ( std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>::size_type i = 0;
                  i < vr.size();
                  i++ )
        {
            vr[i].get() = i + 1;
        }

    }

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
23 25 38 28 26 28 
6 5 1 2 4 3
```

Is not it the best solution is it? :)

EDIT: Maybe there is no sense to use `std::stable_sort` with the functional object. It will be enough to use for loop setting numbers in the reverse order. Something as

```
        for ( std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>::size_type i = 0;
                  i < vr.size();
                  i++ )
        {
            vr[vr.size() + i - 1].get() = i + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should increment when the value is greater than or equal to rather than just greater than, try this:
(*i >= *j)

Comment: The biggest element is equal to itself clearly, and so instead of getting 1st position it is incremented and now is 2nd... (I mean in this case it is smallest which gets 1st, but anyway it will be incremented and will be 2nd after loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to replace the iterators with integers, i.e.: (I assume `<` isn't defined on iterators, but it could be)

```
for (int i = 0; i < vietos.size(); i++)
```

You could increment `n` as well when elements to the left are equal, i.e. when
`vietos[i] > vietos[j] || (vietos[i] == vietos[j] && j < i)`.

---

Alternatively, you could create a `vector<pair<int, int> >`, with each pair containing the element and its index, then `sort` that, and iterate through the sorted vector, setting the index in the pair in the original vector to the index in the sorted vector.

This would give an O(n log n) running time, as opposed to the O(n²) of the above.

Pseudo-code:

```
vector arr
vector<pair> pairs
for i = 0 to n
   pairs.insert(arr[i], i)
sort pairs
for i = 0 to n
   arr[pairs[i].second] = i
```